# Efficient hash for 5 turple (src ip, src port, dst ip, dst port, protocol) for use in tcp hash table

Tags: network-programming

I've found a few samples of functions to fast hash a 5 turple to identify flows in both directions in a tcp connection table for tcp stream reassembly (sha/md5 too slow..)

For example

```
((size_t)(key.src.s_addr) * 59) ^
((size_t)(key.dst.s_addr)) ^
((size_t)(key.sport) << 16) ^
((size_t)(key.dport)) ^
((size_t)(key.proto));
```

Or this one where K is a key with hash table size n, and use the exclusive-OR operator, where the XOR operation can be expressed as

```
H(X) = k1⊕k2⊕...kn
```

or would the following ips/ports/proto which is 97 bits (32+32+16+16+1) give enough randomness without collisions

```
src ip 80.229.161.151 = 1357226391
dst ip 80.229.161.159 = 1357226399
src port 35555 
dst port 80
tcp 6

H(X) = 1357226391 * 97 ⊕ 1357226399 * 97 ⊕ 35555 * 97 ⊕ 80 * 97 ⊕ 6 * 97

hash key = 131654394123 ???
```

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281571413_COMPARISON_OF_HASH_STRATEGIES_FOR_FLOW-BASED_LOAD_BALANCING

Please could someone explain if I'm doing this right?

Or point me to some good papers which explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is: it depends. If the source and destination IPs in your traffic are well-distributed, and the ports are well-distributed, probably any of those are fine for a hash table. However, if you happen to be looking at network traffic that has many connections between a small set of IP addresses or with few distinct ports, things become dicier.

Often, for a hash table, the result of the hash does not need to be perfect. It's not that you need to eliminate collisions altogether, you just don't want them to be frequent, or to result in many entries sharing a small set of hash buckets while many other hash buckets are unused. But that very much depends on your application and from where your network traffic is coming. It's often better to minimize dependence on your inputs and design for the worst case.

One approach often taken to minimize such collisions is to find a fast, effective, non-cryptographic general purpose hash and then just lay out all of the addresses and ports from the tuple in a contiguous buffer, run the hash function on the buffer and fold the result into a hash table index.

From the first link below is this definition:

> Non-cryptographic hash functions take a string as input and compute an integer output. The desirable property of a hash function is that the outputs are evenly distributed across the domain of possible outputs, especially for inputs that are similar. Unlike a cryptographic hash function, these functions are not designed to withstand an effort by an attacker to find a collision.

(To clarify that last sentence, these hash functions *do* minimize collisions; it's just that no effort is made to make them resistant to cryptographic analysis that could lead to *constructed collisions*.)

Take a look at these pages, which have extensive info on "recent" developments:

- http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/01/state-of-hash-functions-2012.html
- http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html

In general, these hashes are going to be slower than an ad-hoc XOR implementation, but much faster than cryptographic hashes like SHA and MD5. Of course, the speed of the hash function is something you have to make a judgment on - but in my experience, obtaining a hash of the TCP/IP 5-tuple to use as an index into a hash table is rarely going to be a significant performance bottleneck. There are usually other parts of the processing that are way more expensive in terms of performance - especially if you'll be doing TCP stream re-assembly: that will require a lot of buffer and memory management, data copying, etc.

Another advantage of using a general purpose hash function: When you're ready to add IPv6 support, no new algorithm is needed. You just lay out a larger buffer, copy your 16-byte IPv6 addresses into it, and run the same hash function.

See also this related question in Software Engineering SE, which has the advantage of being "on-site" for SO:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49550/261672